# Filtering certain types of Requests logged by quarkus.http.access-log

Tags: rest, quarkus

I want to test a new REST-Client I am building, where I'd like to see the exact request which is being built, so I set the `quarkus.http.access-log.enabled=true` property. When starting the Quarkus however, I am being bombarded with the logs of many scheduled requests which are happening simultaneously. The worst of those are several Elasticsearch Scroll-Requests, which return a lot of data which is directly fed into the log.

My idea is, that everything returning a response that contains _index should be filtered, as I know well by now, that my ES-Client is working properly, however it pumps out so much data, that the request I am intending to log is overwritten almost instantly.

So my question: Does somebody know a working (and convenient) method to effectively filter unwanted HTTP-Logs?

I tried setting

```
quarkus.http.access-log.exclude-pattern=(_index+)
```

in an attempt to filter out unwanted requests, but I'm not sure where to continue from there.